# Parsing YAML into nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, yaml

I'm trying to parse a YAML file into a nested dictionary; unfortunately, it only parses the top level elements into a dictionary, but the subordinate elements are parsed into lists.

So say I have the following in my YAML:

```
messages:
  messageA:
    messageText: "Hello World 1" 
  messageB:
    messageText: "Hello World 2"
```

I want to be able to load the yaml like so:

```
stream = file('test.yaml', 'r')
configDict = yaml.load(stream)

print configDict['messages']['messageA']['messageText']
```

but the object its trying to print is a list.

I thought this would create a nested dictionary, not a dictionary of lists.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you show us your current code that parses the above YAML?

Comment: That's all I have. The yaml does load it into a dictionary, but its a dictionary of lists, not a nested dictionary. Which is why the print statement fails.

Comment: Your code as it posted is correct. `configDict` becomes `{'messages': {'messageB': {'messageText': 'Hello World 2'}, 'messageA': {'messageText': 'Hello World 1'}}}` after `yaml.load`. You must be doing something differently locally or there's no way it can become a list.

Comment: I think I figured it out. It didn't like my '-' in front of the elements.

Comment: that makes a difference !

Comment: Yep. The dash indicates a list item.